# Java call to web service not updating boolean properties

Tags: java, web-services, swing, jaxb

Scenario:
I am developing a Swing app which connects to a webservice created by .NET (WCF). Had a few issues, but mostly resolved now. However, I can't seem to update boolean properties. In my entity, I have a boolean property `Gender`:

True = Male,

False = Female,

Null = Unknown/Unspecified.

**CODE:**

```
updatedEntry.setGender(factory.createBoolean(true));
```

Here, `factory` is just an instance of the `ObjectFactory` class generated for me by `Netbeans`. `updatedEntry` is of type `JAXBElement<Boolean>` and I can see that the value is indeed set to True. The update method runs fine without any errors but then I see the database has `NULL` for that column. This is very weird because the other columns are updated just fine.

Just to make sure there wasn't something wrong with my web service, I used **SoapUI** and manually input the parameters.. it worked fine. One thing I noticed was that I could not use the string `True`, but had to input a `1` for it to work. Which makes me wonder; is the `JAXBElement` or some other generated code from my `Netbeans` project sending the value as `true` instead of `1`? Though, if that were the case then why did **SoapUI** throw me an error when I tried that but `Netbeans` did not? Like I said.. from `Netbeans`, all the properties were updated **EXCEPT** the Gender.

Is there some way I can view the generated Soap XML that is generated by Netbeans? Or does anyone have any ideas..., seen this issue before?

Comment: Is this a consequence of specifying [three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) possible values for gender?

Comment: @trashgod, is that a problem in Java? In C# we can create a nullable boolean. How do I overcome this issue? Maybe I can change my code to make it only true/false.. but there must be a proper fix because how would I deal with this with code I don't own the source to?  :-|

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with your framework. Does it offer a more suitable factory, i.e. a conceptual equivalent of `factory.createTrivalent(1)`.

Comment: Hi. No framework here. I have a brand new project created in Netbeans and I added a reference to a webservice. The code for working with the webservice is all generated by Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that will help.

**XML Schema - schema.xsd**

You will get a property of type `JAXBElement<Boolean>` when you have an element that is both `nillable="true"` and `minOccurs="0"`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="root">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="trueValue" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                <element name="falseValue" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                <element name="nullValue" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                <element name="notSetValue" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

**Generated Model - Root**

Below is what the class generated from the `root` elemnent might look like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"trueValue", "falseValue", "nullValue", "notSetValue"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "trueValue", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Boolean> trueValue;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "falseValue", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Boolean> falseValue;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "nullValue", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Boolean> nullValue;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "notSetValue", namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Boolean> notSetValue;

}
```

**Generated Model - ObjectFactory**

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _RootNullValue_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "nullValue");
    private final static QName _RootTrueValue_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "trueValue");
    private final static QName _RootFalseValue_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "falseValue");
    private final static QName _RootNotSetValue_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/schema", "notSetValue");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public Root createRoot() {
        return new Root();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", name = "nullValue", scope = Root.class)
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createRootNullValue(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_RootNullValue_QNAME, Boolean.class, Root.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", name = "trueValue", scope = Root.class)
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createRootTrueValue(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_RootTrueValue_QNAME, Boolean.class, Root.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", name = "falseValue", scope = Root.class)
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createRootFalseValue(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_RootFalseValue_QNAME, Boolean.class, Root.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema", name = "notSetValue", scope = Root.class)
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createRootNotSetValue(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_RootNotSetValue_QNAME, Boolean.class, Root.class, value);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code that will populate each of the `JAXBElement<Boolean>` properties differently to demonstrate each of 4 possible options.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum15170433");

        Root root = new Root();
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

        // set the value to true
        root.setTrueValue(objectFactory.createRootTrueValue(true));

        // set the value to false
        root.setFalseValue(objectFactory.createRootFalseValue(false));

        // set the value to null
        root.setNullValue(objectFactory.createRootNullValue(null));

        // specify the value is unset
        root.setNotSetValue(null);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  We see that the `xsi:nil` attribute is used to represent the `null` value and the unset value is not marshalled.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema">
    <trueValue>true</trueValue>
    <falseValue>false</falseValue>
    <nullValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```